# Limit the speed of a loop or give a thread a Priority in C(Windows)

Tags: c, windows, performance, pthreads

I have a Program in C, which creates a thread with the pthreads Library. In the thread is a loop so that it runs forever. Now my problem is that the loop runs as fast as possible and the Program consumes almost 30% of the CPU. Can I somehow limit the speed of the Loop or give the thread a lower Priority?
Thanks for help!
Edit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define CLOCKS_PER_MSEC 1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC

int CL;

void *driveClock(void *vargp){
    short milli = 0, steptime = 1;
    clock_t before = clock();
    while(1){
        if((clock()-before)*CLOCKS_PER_MSEC>=1){
        CL++;
        before=clock();
        }
    }
} 

int main(){
pthread_t thread_id;
pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL,driveClock, NULL);
pthread_join(thread_id,NULL);
}
```

The program increases the variable CL every millisecond, but consumes 15% of my CPU(Not 30%)

End of edit.

Comment: Perhaps add a `sleep`

Comment: show us the code, please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you @4386427, the `sleep` function does work! But it would still be cool if someone knows how to lower the priority of a thread(if it is possible)

Answer (score 0):

You can change thread's priority by calling [SetThreadPriority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreadpriority)

Like that:

```
SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL);
```

You would need to `#include <windows.h>`